# Installing Ubuntu on a HP Envy 17-j083ca

Tags: installation, dual-boot, hp

Is it possible to install Ubuntu on the laptop i am planning to by.
see [*this*](http://www.costco.ca/HP-Envy-17-j083ca,-Bilingual-Notebook,-Intel%C2%AE-i7-4700MQ,-17.3-in-HD-LED-display.product.100083363.html) website .

I would like to install it as a virtual drive / operating system,
 reading  this [*page*](http://www.itworld.com/software/287946/there-will-be-no-easy-way-install-linux-windows-8-pcs).

i read about the UEFI and how it can cause problem if not completely stop the installation of Ubuntu

Before i buy this laptop i would like to know if i a can install Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

i've been trying to set one of these up and it is possible but very tricky.

i got it mostly working but the dual graphics card option is flakey and unreliable , it seems to make a mess of unity.

the touchscreen works great out of the box and the system feels fast but really not much more than my hi end core 2 duo i. This is the i7 + 12GB RAM + leap one .

i don't think i can be arsed to go through the very tedious process forcing the intel graphics to get it to boot then of sneaking bumblebee into the install (to make the graphics work) and then having to install bumblebee again to once the system is installed and then having to reset unity and the enable the plugins again.  i still couldn't get the panel indicators or global menus back so it wasn't really usable.

if you are thinking of buying one of these you will need to give at least a week of headscratching before its usable. I have nearly 20 years linux experience and this reminded me of the bad old days. do not attempt this if you are newbie.

i don't think thats particularly HP's fault but ubuntu seriously need to release an installer that includes bumblebee because most new laptops now have this setup.

Comment: it seems you don't get these problems if you do install option not the 'try ubuntu' option.  although you still need to add nomodeset acpi.osi=Linux acpi.backlight=Vendor to the boot params.

my apologies to ubuntu for bismirching them.